# How to get engagement points[Goals] for the logged in user

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-api

I have created 2 goals for each page. Now, I want to retrieve the engagement points against the contact[logged in user] from the xDB. Any solution or input would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the client Interactions by using the contact ID.

```
var contactID = Guid.NewGuid(); // Replace with real contact ID

IAsyncQueryable<Interaction> queryable = client.Interactions
                                               .Where(x => x.Contact.Id == contactID);

var enumerator = queryable.GetBatchEnumeratorSync(20);

while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    var interactionBatch = enumerator.Current; 
}
```